# Aggregate data in one column while maintaining/return data in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, sumifs

I have a data frame (called “dk”) like this:

```
Date        Country  ID      Description    Qty
21/05/2014  DK       17423   Frontline      240
26/05/2014  DK       17423   Frontline      360
21/05/2014  DK       73663   Frontline      77
21/05/2014  DK       73663   Frontline      120
...
```

I want to sum quantities per ID. The result should still show me the Country and Description (besides the ID and Qty). And if the dates are different for one ID, then mark with the earlier date, as follow:

```
Date        Country ID      Description      Qty
21/05/2014  DK      17423   Frontline        600
21/05/2014  DK      73663   Frontline        197
```

I’ve used `aggregate`, but it removed info from other columns.

```
data <- aggregate(dk$Qty ~ dk$ID, subset(dk, ID == 17423),sum)

ID      Qty
17423   600
73663   197
```

How could I get the result as described?

Thank you.

Comment: You can add them to the RHS of your aggregate formula. Note if you have multiple countries per ID then you will get a row for each country for each ID etc. e.g. `aggregate( Qty ~ ID + Country + Description, data = dk , sum )`

Comment: Apologies, what is RSH?

Comment: Right hand side of the `~`.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon, what about `Date` column in your solution?

Comment: @DavidArenburg that requirement was added after I commented. In whcih case your solution is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could also do it with `data.table` package (I'll assume your dates are `Date` class)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dk)[, list(Qty = sum(Qty), Date = min(Date)), by = c("ID", "Country", "Description")]
```

If you want to aggregate only by `ID`, you could do the following (when I assume you want the first argument of rest of the columns)

```
setDT(dk)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.numeric(x), sum(x), head(as.character(x), 1))), by = ID]
```

If `Date` isn't `Date` class you could do first

```
dk <- data.table(dk, key = "ID") # Creates a data.table object and sorts it by "ID"
dk[, Date:= as.Date(as.character(Date), "%d/%m/%Y")] #Transforms Date to "Date" class
```

And then you can proceed as usual (just without `setDT` because it's already `data.table` class), for example:

```
dk[, list(Qty = sum(Qty), Date = min(Date)), by = c("ID", "Country", "Description")]

##       ID Country Description Qty       Date
## 1: 17423      DK   Frontline 600 2014-05-21
## 2: 73663      DK   Frontline 197 2014-05-21
```

Comment: I'm still working on the "Date" part. I am trying your code now. And I am happy for the help I've got from Simon

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and help. I need some time to test your code and see it for myself :-)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)

dk %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(Date), format="%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(Date = min(Date),
            Qty = sum(Qty),
            Country = first(Country),
            Description = first(Description))

#     ID       Date Qty Country Description
#1 17423 2014-05-21 600      DK   Frontline
#2 73663 2014-05-21 197      DK   Frontline
```

This way you will get one row per `ID`, the sum of `Qty` for that `ID`, the minimum `Date` per `ID` and the first entries of `Country` and `Description` per ID. Note that if you group by for example, `ID` and `Description` and you have different descriptions per `ID`, your result would look different. It is only because your sample data has no different descriptions and Countries, that the results would look the same.

Comment: beginneR,I like your code :-) and surely it will be useful for next time ...And, sorry I failed to explain my situation properly. I needed to sum the quantities per "ID", but "Country" must be unique. Thought in the beginning that I would break the data down by country, so I only had to deal with the IDs. Learned now that there is a smarter way to do it :D

Comment: @user3206981 no problem. Just for your reference, it would be very easy to change my code to your needs. You would only need to change `group_by` to `group_by(ID, Country) %.%` and remove `Country = ... ` from the `summarize()`